# How to disable the touchscreen in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: 21.04, touchscreen, wayland, xinput

I faced a problem after a couple of days that my malfunctioned touchscreen was on unexpectedly, despite setting `MatchIsTouchscreen "off"` at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

How to make it disabled just like Ubuntu 20 and the older versions?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20, what version are you running?

Comment: @David https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-new-in-ubuntu-desktop-20-04-lts

Comment: You have edited the question to say 21.04 and that link says 20.04 not sure that is any clearer.

Comment: You didn't get my question, it's about Ubuntu 21.04, the touchscreen disabling issue starts with that version. I was wondering if it can be disabled like 20.04 or older versions. That link is about Ubuntu 20.04 which you said it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of searching a solution to that is keep that configuration `MatchIsTouchscreen "off"` and to make Xinput runs by default again to apply that configuration.

To disable Wayland:

1. open the file: `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
2. uncomment (remove # from): `WaylandEnable=false`